# Sharepoint Designer 2013 - How to add a web part zone?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a problem in Sharepoint 2013.

I'm using Designer 2013 and I'm trying to add another web part zone. As you can see from the picture, there is a web part zone to the left. I know how to decrease the width of the web part zone, so there's space for another. But I don't know, **how to actually add a new web part zone**.

Designer 2013 doesn't have design view. 
 **Does anyone know how I could add a web part zone to the right this time?**

Thanks in advance.

[image: The problem]

Comment: You can try to open existing web part page and then copy web part zone markup.

Answer (score 3):

You can add it manually if that "Web Part Zone" button is greyed out in SP Designer:

```
<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>


<WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager id="m" runat="Server"/>
<div data-name="WebPartZone">
    <div xmlns:ie="ie">
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="x0e5f5212505f48a9aac43df13eeae4f9" AllowCustomization="True" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" LockLayout="True" Orientation="Vertical">
            <ZoneTemplate>
               <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
            </ZoneTemplate>
        </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
    </div>
</div>
```

Source:  Microsoft (2015).  How to:  Add a Web Part zone snipped in SharePoint 2013.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862341.aspx

Comment: Full instruction here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126449/add-web-part-zone-in-custom-page-layout?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @GennadyG The background isn't bad, but, as a caveat, if you go to that other link, they have a lot of unnecessary instructions and is why I didn't copy that stuff and reference it, before - like doing stuff with the Snippet Gallery and replacing divs.  You literally *only* want to add what I have above directly into whatever page you are on.  It will literally create a WebPartZone wherever you place the `<div data-name="WebPartZone">...</div>` and you can then use the "Add a Web Part" button to add your web part from there.

Answer (score 2):

Open Designer -> sitepages-> add webpart page from the top of the ribbon ->
Edit the page -> see it is saved -> if saved means-> top of ribbon click on Insert-> addWebpartzone option is available.

Comment: Error : **can not add web part zone because this locked by master page**